# Passing TimeUnits and converting to milliseconds

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, timeunit

How can I make an API for a class that the user passes a `TimeUnit` e.g. minutes, seconds, hours and a number and keep the millisec value internally in the class.
The following seems the only way?

```
void someMethodDays(int numOfDays) {  
   this.longValue = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(numOfDays);  
}  

void someMethodHour(int numOfHours) {  
   this.longValue = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(numOfDays);  
} etc
```

Is this the only way? A method per value with a descriptive name for argument?

Comment: What about `public void someMethod(TimeUnit unit, int numberOfUnits)`?

Answer (score 3):

You could model your class after a well-known and tested class: `java.time.LocalDate`, which provides the [`plus(long, TemporalUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) method.

Similarly, you could create a `someMethod(long, TimeUnit)` method that allows callers to pass in arbitrary amounts of any `TimeUnit`.

```
void someMethod(long amount, TimeUnit unit) {
    this.longValue = unit.toMillis(amount);
}
```

Note that `LocalDate` *also* provides specialized methods for adding certain common units of time, like `plusDays()`. That gives the caller the ability to decide which is clearer for the code they're writing:

```
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays(1);
```

```
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plus(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you don’t need to develop your own class; that you’ll be reinventing the wheel. I suggest you use the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class.

To convert from some time unit to a `Duration`:

```
    System.out.println(Duration.of(3, ChronoUnit.HOURS));
```

Or alternatively:

```
    System.out.println(Duration.ofHours(3));
```

Output is the same in both cases:

> PT3H

It prints a little funny; this means a span of time of 3 hours. The format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

```
    System.out.println(Duration.of(2, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
```

> PT48H

48 hours; that’s correct.

```
    System.out.println(Duration.of(327864523, ChronoUnit.MICROS));
```

> PT5M27.864523S

A span of 5 minutes 27.864523 seconds.

If you need to convert to milliseconds, the method is built in:

```
    Duration dur = Duration.of(284, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
    System.out.println("" + dur.toMillis() + " milliseconds");
```

> 17040000 milliseconds

`Duration` is part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and of course works well with the other classes from that API.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Documentation: the `Duration` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601; section on durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)